# Diameter of a random graph

Tags: graphs, reference-request

I'm considering the standard Erdös/Renyi $G(n,p)$ model where we have $n$ nodes and each possible edge is sampled independently with probability $p = \frac{1}{n^\epsilon}$.

It is relatively straightforward to show that, starting from any node $u$, the *expected* number of hops to reach every other node is $1/\epsilon$. However, this does not say much about the probability of having a diameter of $1/\epsilon$. 
(I could apply Markov's inequality, but that gives a rather weak bound.)

Thus I'm looking for a reference to a concentration result that states that the diameter of such a random graph is $O(1/\epsilon)$ with probability at least $1 - o(1)$.

Comment: Repeated application of Chernoff's bound should show that if you perform DFS from some fixed vertex, then you cover the entire graph in $O(1/\epsilon)$ steps whp.

Comment: I suppose you mean BFS right?

Comment: Right, I meant BFS.